# How to verify that Protractor e2e that success in local machine will run the same on the Jenkins (Docker)

Tags: google-chrome, docker, jenkins, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to comprehend the diff between my that run successfully on localmachine:

```
 Mac
 Chrome v71
 ChromeDriver 2.45
__________________
 Angular 5
```

But for unknown reason they don't run on Jenkins.

```
This is what I get in console:
[31m- [39m[31mFailed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
    (Session info: headless chrome=70.0.3538.67)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615279 (12b89733300bd268cff3b78fc76cb8f3a7cc44e5),platform=Linux 3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64 x86_64)[39m
  [31m- [39m[31mFailed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
    (Session info: headless chrome=70.0.3538.67)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615279 (12b89733300bd268cff3b78fc76cb8f3a7cc44e5),platform=Linux 3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64 x86_64)[39m
```

The only diff it's that it doesn't on the latest chrome.

Currently I'm unable to run it local docker because of our Enterprise Proxy. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

PS:

1. How to downgrade the Chrome on local machine?
2. How to specify specific Chrome version to run or maybe driver that will run the tests?
3. I have some tests that started to fail because of v71 - they Download Files related. Maybe there is a fix for that too.

This all begun after Chrome update on Docker and update of Chrome (Google fault).
(Chrome v67 everything worked great - how to use it with Protractor)

Comment: if the chromeDriver Version does not "fit" with the Chrome Version which runs the tests strange things happend in our tests as well, thats all i can say

Comment: @b3nc1 thanks for the comment :) But what's wrong with that? Why they don't fix the issues with backward capabilities - support? How did you handled this?

Comment: Did you tried to run same test using grid?

Comment: hey in my docker file before I run protractor I run `npm run update-webdriver` so I always have the latest webdriver. Try doing so too even if for some reason you need to stick to the older version. In this case you'll at least narrow down possible problem